# How to truncate rest of the text in a file after finding a specific text pattern, in unix?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, grep

I have a HTML PAGE which I have extracted in unix using wget command, in that after the word "Check list" I need to remove all of the text and with the remaining I am trying to grep some data. I am unable to think on a way which can be helpful for removing the text after a keyword. if I do

```
s/Check list.*//g
```

It just removes the line , I want everything below that to be gone. How do I perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `q` to instruct GNU `sed` to quit, thus ending processing, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
123
456
789
```

and say you want to jettison everything beyond `5`, then you could do

```
sed '/5/{s/5.*//;q}' file.txt
```

which gives output

```
123
4
```

Explanation: for line having `5`, substitute `5` and everything beyond it with empty string (i.e. delete it), then `q`. Observe that *lowercase* `q` is used to provide printing of altered line before quiting.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*

Answer (score 4):

The other solutions you have so far require non-POSIX-mandatory tools (GNU sed, GNU awk, or perl) so YMMV with their availability and will read the whole file into memory at once.

These will work in any awk in any shell on every Unix box and only read 1 line at a time into memory:

```
awk -F 'Check list' '{print $1} NF>1{exit}' file
```

or:

```
awk 'sub(/Check list.*/,""){f=1} {print} f{exit}' file
```

With GNU awk for multi-char RS you could do:

```
awk -v RS='Check list' '{print; exit}' file
```

but that would still read all of the text before `Check list` into memory at once.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which `sed` version you have, maybe

```
sed -z 's/Check list.*//'
```

The `/g` flag is useless as you only want to replace everything once.

If your `sed` does not have the `-z` option (which says to use the ASCII null character as line terminator instead of newline; this hinges on your file not containing any actual nulls, but that should trivially be true for any text file), try Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/Check list.*//s'
```

Unlike `sed -z`, this explicitly says to slurp the entire file into memory (the argument to `-0` is the octal character code of a terminator character, but `777` is not a valid terminator character at all, so it always reads the entire file as a single "line") so this works even if there are spurious nulls in your file. The final `s` flag says to include newline in what `.` matches (otherwise `s/.*//` would still only substitute on the matching physical line).

I assume you are aware that removing *everything* will violate the integrity of the HTML file; it needs there to be a closing tag for every start tag near the beginning of the document (so if it starts with `<html><body>` you should keep `</body></html>` just before the end of the file, for example).

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you could make use of `RS` variable and then set field separator to regex with word boundaries and then print the very first field as per need.

```bash
awk -v RS="^$" -v FS='\\<check_list\\>' '{print $1}'  Input_file
```